# Django - Perform a complex operation in .update()

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    full_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Some `full_address` ends with "Region".  Examples:

1. 123 Main Street, Markham, York Region
2. 1 Bloor Street, Mississauga, Peel Region

I want to remove "Region" from any `full_address` field that ends with it.

Here is one possible solution, but it is slow, since you need to go over each `Address` one by one:

```
for i in Address.objects.filter(full_address__endswith=' Region'):
    i.full_address = i.full_address[:-7]
    i.save()
```

Is there some way to achieve the above function using `Address.objects.update()`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) here

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

Address.objects.filter(full_address__endswith=' Region').update(
    full_address=Func(
        F('full_address'),
        Value(' Region'), Value(''),
        function='replace',
    )
)
```

Note that if you think you could get a string that *contained* the text `' Region'`  as well as *ending* with that string, this will replace both with the empty string. It seems unlikely, but if you want to be especially careful you could use `regexp_replace` instead of `replace` and use the appropriate expression for the first `Value` (i.e. `Value(' Region$')`) to ensure you only match the one part you want to replace.

Comment: Yes I will have to use `regexp_replace`, because `' Region'` could appear in street names in the form of something like `' Regional Road 25'`